# Opening two workbooks with Xlwings in same app instance, making one visible and one not

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am making a program using Xlwings and Python, which allows a user to enter information on one excel workbook, and outputs data based on calculations which reference another workbook.

I am trying to get the workbook that needs to be edited visible and the one that contains reference data not visible.

My program used to work fine by opening the reference data first and importing it all into arrays in Python, then closing it, before opening the main workbook.

```
Ductapp = xw.App(visible=False)
Ductwb = Ductapp.books.open('Path to reference file')
...
Ductwb.close()
Ductapp.quit()

Mainwb = xw.Book('Path to main file')
...
Mainwb.close()
```

However now, I need to use the reference workbook whilst editing the main workbook (there are some elements that I cannot import into Python to use) so this method no longer works. When the main workbook opens now, it throws an error. If I add the main workbook into the same app instance, neither book is visible, and if I set the visible to True, both are visible.

Is there a way to make one visible and one not?